# How to change property key in gremlin with graph engine as Janusgraph and storage backend as cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using cassandra 4.0 with Janusgraph 6.0, I have n nodes with Label as "januslabel" and property as "janusproperty", I want to change property name to "myproperty", I have tried the answer of this link, [Rename property with Gremlin in Azure Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318508/rename-property-with-gremlin-in-azure-cosmos-db)
but I was not able to do this permanently, what I mean with permanently is that whenever I do restart cassandra or janusgraph I get the old property name "janusproperty".

How can I change this permanently?

Comment: Are you making sure to commit the transaction?

Comment: No, I am not committing it. I don't know how to do, please tell me syntax for that.

Comment: I have committed and now it works. Thanks a lot for guiding me.

Comment: I’m glad that was it. I’ll add an answer in case others search for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

When using JanusGraph, if no transaction is currently open, one will be automatically  started once a Gremlin query is issued. Subsequent queries are also part of that  transaction. Transactions need to be explicitly committed for any changes to be persisted using something like `graph.tx().commit()`. Transactions that are not committed will eventually time out and changes will be lost.